# Jasper Report não abre em produção

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Estou usando o Jasper Report para gerar os relatórios. Quando estou em localhost, exporta normalmente, mas em produção não exporta. Vou colar aqui o método de exportação do arquivo:

```
exportRelatorio(listReport, out, "/reports/relatorio.jrxml");

private void exportRelatorio(Collection<?> collection, OutputStream out, String jrxml) {
        try {

            InputStream fonte = getClass().getResourceAsStream(jrxml);
            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(fonte);
            fonte.close();

            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(collection));

            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }´´´
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Já tentou ver se não é algum problema com o caminho do relatorio.jrxml

Comment: Olá Eduardo! Já verifiquei, em ambiente local funciona corretamente, apenas quando subo para ambiente de produção que acontece erro. Sei que provavelmente é um problema com o caminho do arquivo, porém não sei como posso resolver

Comment: Tem acesso ao log de produção onde o erro ocorre? Se sim, ele pode ser muito útil. Poste-o.